# rspec, capybara javascript driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have this in my test:

```
let!(:user) { create(:user) }
```

When I run test without `:js`

```
def create
   11:     byebug
=> 12:     if @user = login(params[:email], params[:password])
   13:       logger.info "--------------"
   14:       logger.info "found user"
   15:       redirect_back_or_to root_path, notice: t(:log_in_is_successful_notice)
   16:     else
(byebug) User.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 291, email: "test@test.com", crypted_password: "$2a$10$rOKscDDidaf93p/e9IOceOCGozns5AJ2zSLMO68jRZO...", created_at: "2016-06-22 20:15:55", updated_at: "2016-06-22 20:15:55", salt: "qpSR5US81thfoTn8pphQ", remember_me_token: nil, remember_me_token_expires_at: nil, reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_token_expires_at: nil, reset_password_email_sent_at: nil, current_block_id: nil, locale: "ru">]>
```

But when I run this test with `:js`, I got this:

```
 11:     byebug
=> 12:     if @user = login(params[:email], params[:password])
   13:       logger.info "--------------"
   14:       logger.info "found user"
   15:       redirect_back_or_to root_path, notice: t(:log_in_is_successful_notice)
   16:     else
(byebug) User.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
(byebug) User.all.take
nil
```

I'm using `webkit` as js driver:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not disabled transactional testing so objects created in your test thread are not visible in your apps thread.  You need to read the [Transactions and Database Setup](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup) section of the Capybara README, and then configure something like [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example) to handle switching database strategies for you